# gnus viewer for attachments

Tags: gnus

I recently started using gnus to view my emails. Opening attachments is still the most annoying part for me and I am trying to address that.

The behaviour I would like is: If the attachment is text-based then open in an emacs buffer in the same instance I am using, otherwise open using the system's `xdg-open`.

According to 
[emacswiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MimeTypesWithGnus), I created a file `~/.mailcap` with the single line

```
    application/*; xdg-open %s
```

But then this line is just added to the application list in `/etc/mailcap`, which I have no control over, and I have to select `xdg-open` in the list that is shown to me every time I try to open an attachment. How can I prevent gnus from reading that file and instead directly open an attachment with `xdg-open`?

Also, how do I get text files to open in a buffer?

Finally, is there a way to open the attachment without going all the way to the file name in the email? Perhaps by showing a list of attachment and letting me choose one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So many questions at once.

- emacs-27 will prefer ~/.mailcap entries to the system ones. See
  [Mailcap
  precedence](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-diffs/2018-04/msg00205.html)
  for details. You can build the emacs master branch from source to pick up those changes.
- The answer to your third question is: Check out the <kbd>K-</kbd>
  bindings in the Summary buffer:

```
    K C             gnus-article-view-part-as-charset
    K E             gnus-article-encrypt-body
    K H             gnus-article-browse-html-article
    K O             gnus-article-save-part-and-strip
    K b             gnus-summary-display-buttonized
    K c             gnus-article-copy-part
    K d             gnus-article-delete-part
    K e             gnus-article-view-part-externally
    K i             gnus-article-inline-part
    K j             gnus-article-jump-to-part
    K m             gnus-summary-repair-multipart
    K o             gnus-article-save-part
    K r             gnus-article-replace-part
    K t             gnus-article-view-part-as-type
    K v             gnus-article-view-part
    K |             gnus-article-pipe-part
```

(they all take numerical prefix arguments to specify which part you're talking about)

- For youre second question, you're looking for the
  unfortunately-named `gnus-article-copy-part`, which will create a buffer containing that part.